# how to hide a measure group in ssas 2005 for excel 2007

Tags: ssas

If I hide the measures in the measure group, the measure group will be invisible in cube browser in BIDS. But in excel 2007, it still shows the measure group with no measures but related dimensions. So any idea to hide the measure group in excel 2007? I guess this is client related since cube browser in BIDS is hiding the measure group.

update:
I googled and found I can set up a perspective to hide the measure group. But our's is standard edition, which does not support this feature...

Answer (score 1):

This feature is not supported in SSAS.See this [link](http://raphaelmsbithoughts.wordpress.com/2011/07/18/analysis-services-feature-suggestion-managing-measure-group-visibility/) by Raphael with more details about this. Raphael has also created a feature suggestion to ask the SSAS team to allow us to properly handle measure group visibility, so that reporting tools like excel know exactly how to behave when we want to hide a measure group. You can find the suggestion [here](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/679279/be-able-to-manage-measure-group-visibility).